# error trying to create order in paypal with guzzle and laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to create an order in paypal with laravel and guzzle and it throws me this error:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: `POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders` resulted in a
> `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed,
> syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id (truncated...)

my controller code:

```
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();   $client = new Client(['base_uri' =>  'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/']);
    
    
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,        
    ];
    
    $params = [
        'intent' =>  'CAPTURE', 
        'purchase_units' => [
            'amount' => [
                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                'value' => '100.00'
            ]
        ]
    ];
    //dd($params);
    

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'orders', [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'form_params' => $params
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `$params` object is invalid. It should be a *list* of `purchase_unit` items, not an associative array.

```php
        $params = [
            'intent' =>  'CAPTURE',
            'purchase_units' => [               
                [
                    'amount' => [
                        'currency_code' => 'USD',
                        'value' => '100.00'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body

Comment: what about convert $params to php object!

Answer (score 0):

> 'form_params' => $params

This is used to send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request, which the PayPal API does not use.

You should be posting a plain string, JSON encoded. In place of `form_params` try passing the `json` key to guzzle in the request, or read its documentation on how to send json

---

edit: not sure whether that change makes a difference, but the other answer is correct that purchase_units needs to be an indexed array of purchase_unit objects -- likely only one of them.

Comment: I transformed to json encoded, but I still got the same results